# Example: Differentiable, NOT locally lipschitz?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

Is being differentiable (Gateaux or Frechet) at ONE point enough for being locally lipschitz?
If not, can you provide a counterexample?

Comment: $$x^2\sin \frac{1}{x^2}$$

Comment: The derivative is unbounded in every neighbourhood of $0$. Although it is everywhere differentiable, it is not locally Lipschitz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any function that is differentiable at exactly one point and is also continuous just at that point. Such a function can't be locally Lipschtiz, since being locally Lipschitz entails being continuous at a neighborhood of the point.

Comment: Sure, but what function is differentiable at a point and als continuous only at that point?

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=-x^2$ if $x$ is irrational.

Comment: $x^2\chi_\mathbb{Q}(x)$ at zero